# Error while excecuting a join query with sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have three entities Service, Sale, and SalesServices. The relationship within sales and services is of many to many:

associations.js

```
const User = require('./User.model');
const Employee = require('./Employee.model');
const Sale = require('./Sale.model');
const Service = require('./Service.model');

Sale.belongsToMany(Service, { 
    through: 'SalesServices', 
    as:'services', 
    onDelete: 'CASCADE' 
});

Service.belongsToMany(Sale, { 
    through: 'SalesServices', 
    as:'sales', 
    onDelete: 'CASCADE' 
});

User.hasOne(Employee, { 
    foreignKey: 'user_id', 
    as: 'Employee', 
    onDelete: 'CASCADE' 
});

Employee.belongsTo(User, { 
    foreignKey: 'user_id', 
    as: 'User', 
    onDelete: 'CASCADE' 
});


module.exports = { User, Employee, Sale, Service };
```

The following is my model Service.js

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../config/db');

const Service = sequelize.define('Service', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    service_code: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true    
    },
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true    
    },
    description: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
 
    },
    service_date: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    price: {
        type: Sequelize.DECIMAL(20,2),
        allowNull: false,
    },

});

module.exports = Service;
```

This is my Sale.model.js

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../config/db');

const Sale = sequelize.define('Sale', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    employee_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references: {
            model: 'employees',
            key: 'id'
        },
        required: true,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    customer_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references: {
            model: 'customers',
            key: 'id'
        },
        required: true,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    
});

module.exports = Sale;
```

And this is my SalesServices.model.js

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../config/db');

const SalesServices = sequelize.define('SalesServices', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    sale_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        references: {
            model: 'sales', 
            key: 'id'
        },
    },
    service_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        references: {
            model: 'services',
            key: 'id'
        },
    }
}, {
    tableName: 'SalesServices', 
    timestamps: false, 
});

module.exports = SalesServices;
```

I am trying to get all my sales in my controller, but as it is a many to many relationship I want to bring with my sales, all the services related to each sale.

The following is my method:

```
//@route   GET /api/v1/sales
//@desc    Get all sales
//@access  Private

exports.getSales = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    const sales = await Sale.findAll({
       include: [{
         model: Service,
         as: "services",
       }],
    });
   
    res.status(200).json({ sales });
   });
```

And I get the following Query:

```
Executing (default): SELECT `Sale`.`id`, `Sale`.`employee_id`, `Sale`.`customer_id`, `Sale`.`createdAt`, `Sale`.`updatedAt`, `services`.`id` AS `services.id`, `services`.`service_code` AS `services.service_code`, `services`.`name` AS `services.name`, `services`.`description` AS `services.description`, `services`.`service_date` AS 
`services.service_date`, `services`.`price` AS `services.price`, `services`.`createdAt` AS `services.createdAt`, `services`.`updatedAt` AS `services.updatedAt`, `services->SalesServices`.`createdAt` AS `services.SalesServices.createdAt`, `services->SalesServices`.`updatedAt` AS `services.SalesServices.updatedAt`, `services->SalesServices`.`SaleId` AS `services.SalesServices.SaleId`, `services->SalesServices`.`ServiceId` AS `services.SalesServices.ServiceId` FROM `Sales` AS `Sale` LEFT OUTER JOIN ( `SalesServices` AS `services->SalesServices` INNER JOIN `Services` AS `services` ON `services`.`id` = `services->SalesServices`.`ServiceId`) ON `Sale`.`id` = `services->SalesServices`.`SaleId`;
```

And the error is just `Error Query.run`

Why is this happening if my relationships are well defined?

Comment: Did you try to run this query in some DB editor/viewer?